# html input save var into javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to save a user input from an HTML file into a `.js` file.
Can someone help me and teach me how to do it?

**HTML FILE**

```
<form >
  <label for="size">Enter size:</label>
  <input type="text" id="size" ><br>
  <label for="color">Enter color:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
var item_size = ""
var item_color = ""
// (here the codes continues but i need only to save user input on this 2 var.)
```

This 2 part needs to be in 2 separate files, a `.html` and a `.js` one, and not on a single HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using forms, and using getElementById to get all the values. Here's a sample script that does that

```js
function getData() {
    var item_size = document.getElementById('size').value
    var item_color = document.getElementById('color').value
    document.getElementById('size').value = ""
    document.getElementById('color').value = ""
    console.log(item_size)
    console.log(item_color)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <label for="size">Enter size:</label>
        <input type="text" id="size" ><br>
        <label for="color">Enter color:</label>
        <input type="text" id="color"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="getData()" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, using forms can be very useful in combination with the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Comment: Sure, but not in this example, plus he wanted the input in 2 vars, not a single form variable

Answer (score 0):

make below changes in code. On click of submit button or any other event based on your requirement call java script method. One more suggestion, declare these variables inside method else it will become global which is not a good practice.

**Java Script**

```
var item_size = ""
var item_color = ""

function saveValue() {
 item_size = document.getElementById("size").value;
 item_color = document.getElementById("color").value;

 console.log(item_size);
 console.log(item_color);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="size">Enter size:</label>
<input type="text" id="size"><br>
<label for="color">Enter color:</label>
<input type="text" id="color"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="saveValue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `submit` event on the form. This event will be fired whenever the submit button inside a form is either clicked or triggered through keyboard input.

With the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) you are able to extract all values from the form into a single object. These values will be stored in the object based on the `name` attribute on the `<input>` fields, so make sure those attributes are there.

Prevent the default submit event to prevent the form from triggering a reload.

```js
const form = document.forms['item-form'];
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const itemSize = formData.get('size');
  const itemColor = formData.get('color');
  console.log(itemSize, itemColor);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form name="item-form">
  <label for="size">Enter size:</label>
  <input type="text" id="size" name="size"><br>
  <label for="color">Enter color:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color" name="color"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `document` object followed by the `getElementById` function. Inside the brackets, open a quotes and inside that write the ID of the input, and after the `getElementById` function write `.value`. Here's the code:

```html
<form>
  <label for="size">Enter size:</label>
  <input type="text" id="size" ><br>
  <label for="color">Enter color:</label>
  <input type="text" id="color"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
var item_size = document.getElementById("size").value;
var item_color = document.getElementById("color").value;
```